# Unable to display Bash prompt variable in tmux with same decoration as in bash

Tags: bash, tmux

I am curious about why my bash variable PS1 is not the same in tmux as in bash.

Here is my PS1 variable
PS1=`{debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[06;32m\] \w\[\033[00m\] $ \[\033[06;31m\]$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")\[\033[00;00m\]`

Note that I have set text decoration to `06` for my working directory special character `\w`.
Basically this text-decoration causes the corresponding special character to blink. This works fine in bash, but when I start tmux even though I get a colored output - the text decoration doesn't work (the working directory in my case doesn't blink).

I have in my .tmux.conf file the following line.

```
set-option -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"
```

Can I make it work in the same way as in my bash?